# i'm not seeing knockout value coming through onto my bound textfield

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, knockout.js

I have the following code although I'm not seeing the value of the firstname coming through onto the form textbox?  I can see in firebug that the value is correct?
Any help much appreciated!

**Firebug - console window**

```
pageModel.firstname()  // shows value: 'Jane'
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="Firstname" name="Firstname" data-bind="value: pageModel.firstname'" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    pageModel = (function() {          
        var init = function(data) {
            this.firstname = ko.observable(data.Member.FirstName);
            ...
            ...
        };
        return { init: init };  // Revealing module pattern
    })();

    ko.applyBindings(pageModel);

    var serverModel = <%=ViewData.Model.ToJson() %>;

    pageModel.init(serverModel);
});
```

**JSON object**

```
 {"Member":{FirstName: 'Jane'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you should just be using data-bind="value: firstname" without the ' and the pageModel.

It's a lot easier to read if you create a ViewModel which you can create an object of.

html:

```
<input id="Firstname" name="Firstname" data-bind="value: firstname" />
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    var serverModel = <%=ViewData.Model.ToJson() %>;
    var viewModel = new ViewModel(serverModel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

var ViewModel = function(serverModel) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstname = ko.observable(serverModel.Member.FirstName);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view model is `pageModel` so your bindings just reference objects on the view model.  Change your binding to:

```
data-bind='value: firstName'
```

And you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems there:

1. You're applying bindings before you initialize the view model. If you open your web console, you'll see an error from KO saying it has no idea what `pageModel` is.
2. Even once you initialize the model, it still doesn't have a `pageModel` property. Just a `firstname` property.
3. You have an extra `'` at the end of the binding.

Separately, your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you're not declaring `pageModel` anywhere.

Some fixes:

```
$(function() {

    // Added `var` here
    var pageModel = (function() {          
        var init = function(data) {
            this.firstname = ko.observable(data.Member.FirstName);
            ...
            ...
        };
        return { init: init };  // Revealing module pattern
    })();


    var serverModel = <%=ViewData.Model.ToJson() %>;

    pageModel.init(serverModel);

    // Moved this to end
    ko.applyBindings(pageModel);
});
```

and in the HTML:

```
<input id="Firstname" name="Firstname" data-bind="value: firstname" />
<!-- No `pageModel.` here -------------------------------^        ^
     No single quote here ---------------------------------------/
-->
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/jogecuke/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/jogecuke/1/edit))

If you really want to apply the bindings *before* calling `pageModel.init`, you'll need to do something to create the `firstname` observable, and then later in `init` update that observable using the `data` argument (rather than creating a new one).

Comment: There is also a quote in `data-bind="value: firstname'"` after `firstname` that should be removed

Comment: @GôTô: Thanks, yeah, I found that when doing the live example.

Comment: I've written this way to avoid pluting the global namespace(?)

Comment: @JamesRadford: Not quite sure which "this way" you mean, but by failing to declare `pageModel`, you were adding a global. By declaring it (within the function you're passing to `$()`), we keep it from being a global. There are no globals created by the JavaScript code above. (There's one created by the HTML, indirectly because there's an `id` on the input field -- browsers create global variables for those `id` values that refer to the elements [sadly]. Since you're using KO, you shouldn't need that `id`...)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the context of your data binding. It's already pageModel. You do not need to repeat the context to knockout. As good as `data-bind="with: pageModel"` and the bindings inside this element will not need `pageModel` to be repeated.